# I am new to mongodb and jsp ,I tried to create login page with mongodb database connection using netbeans

Tags: java, mongodb, jsp, netbeans

```
<%-- 
    Document   : login
    Created on : Sep 19, 2016, 11:04:06 AM
    Author     : admin
--%>
<%@page import="com.mongodb.DBCursor"%>
<%@page import="com.mongodb.DBCollection"%>
<%@page import="com.mongodb.DB"%>
<%@page import="com.mongodb.MongoClient"%>
<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN"
   "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">

<html>
    <head>

<title>Login</title>
<!-- Custom Theme files -->
<link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all"/>


<!--script-->
<script src="js/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/easyResponsiveTabs.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
            <script type="text/javascript">
                $(document).ready(function () {
                    $('#horizontalTab').easyResponsiveTabs({
                        type: 'default', //Types: default, vertical, accordion
                        width: 'auto', //auto or any width like 600px
                        fit: true   // 100% fit in a container
                    });
                });

</script>
<!--script-->

<%@page import="mongo.*" %>
</head>
    </head>
    <body>
        <%-- <form action="MongoConnection">--%>



 <%try{   

     // To connect to mongodb server
     MongoClient mongoClient = new MongoClient( "localhost" , 27017 );

     // Now connect to your databases
     DB db = mongoClient.getDB( "nandha" );
     System.out.println("Connect to database successfully");


     DBCollection coll = db.getCollection("priya");
     System.out.println("Collection admin selected successfully");

     DBCursor cursor = coll.find();
     int i = 1;

     while (cursor.hasNext()) { 
        System.out.println("Inserted Document: "+i); 
        System.out.println(cursor.next()); 
        i++;
     }

  }catch(Exception e){
     System.err.println( e.getClass().getName() + ": " + e.getMessage() );
  }
```

}%>

```
              <form method="post" action="product-list.jsp">
        <div class="head">
        <div class="logo">
            <div class="logo-top">
                <h1>Syzygy Spa Login</h1>
            </div>
            <div class="logo-bottom">
                <img src="images/logo.png" >
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="login">
            <div class="sap_tabs">
                <div id="horizontalTab" style="display: block; width: 100%; margin: 0px;">
                    <ul class="resp-tabs-list">
                        <li class="resp-tab-item" aria-controls="tab_item-0" role="tab"><span>Login Here ...</span></li>
                        <div class="clearfix"></div>
                    </ul>
                    <div class="resp-tabs-container">
                        <div class="tab-1 resp-tab-content" aria-labelledby="tab_item-0">
                            <div class="login-top">
                                <form>
                                    <input type="text" class="email" placeholder="Email" required/>
                                    <input type="password" class="password" placeholder="Password" required/>
                                </form>
                                <div class="login-bottom login-bottom1">
                                    <div class="submit">
                                        <input type="submit" value="LOGIN"/>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="clear"></div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>

                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="clear"></div>
    </div>

    </body>
</html>
```

But i have  bugs in mongodb connection

port:localhost:27017
my database name :nandha.
my collection name:priya

{ "_id" : { "$oid" : "57e3b941ed64421e189a8a0b"} , "name" : "nandha" , "age" : 26 ,password:"bharani, "created Date" : { "$date" : "2016-09-22T10:58:09.792Z"}}

Comment: Please provide some more explanations of your code, what you are trying to do and what issue you are experiencing *exactly*. It is hard to find an error in dozens or even hundreds lines of code. Please read [How to create a *Minimal*, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Then, update and *improve your question*.

Answer (score 0):

You can find an example, I hope you serve help

https://www.mkyong.com/mongodb/java-authentication-access-to-mongodb/